# Scala - Superclass instantiate its subclass in its method?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I am taking the 'Functional Programming Principles in Scala' course on Coursera. In Assignment 3, there is a task to filter a tweet set with a predicate, with some structures provided:

```
abstract class TweetSet {
  /**
   * This method takes a predicate and returns a subset of all the elements
   * in the original set for which the predicate is true.
   *
   * Question: Can we implment this method here, or should it remain abstract
   * and be implemented in the subclasses?
   */
   def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = ???

  /**
   * This is a helper method for `filter` that propagetes the accumulated tweets.
   */
   def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet

  /* Some Other Code */

}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = ???
}
```

I am able to figure out the `filter` method in the abstract class with

```
def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = filterAcc(p, new Empty)
```

which is the same as most of the solutions I can find online.

The question is, the abstract super class `TweetSet` instantiates one of its subclass `Empty` in its method. Is this a good programming exercise? Won't it break the class hierarchy, or the purpose of abstraction?

Comment: From the code you gave I would suppose you should implement `filter` in abstract class *in terms of* `filterAcc` which should stay abstract and then implement specific `filterAcc` in each subclass.

Comment: @Łukasz Just corrected a typo - and that is exactly what I am doing in the `filter` method. However if you look at the implementation, this method calls `new Empty` which instantiate its subclass - but a super class is not supposed to know what subclass inherits from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Won't it break the class hierarchy, or the purpose of abstraction?

In a general sense you are right. But in this case abstraction is not used as a way to make multiple implementations possible, a TweetSet without `Empty` or `NonEmpty` would not make sense. In this case abstraction is used give a uniform interface to a `TweetSet`.

General rule to thumb is that depending on subtypes is allowed if they are in the same file.